How do I add 22.04 repositories to 24.04?
I need to use a prior version of lyx that is unavailable in 24.04. How do I add this repository? I guess I'm asking about the Signed-By line in the newly formatted Ubuntu.sources file that replaces the sources.list file.

Please add more details. Which version of lyx? Where is it available? Also, why do you want to do this? It may be another XY Problem

Thanks for the response. lyx 2.36. It is, in many ways, incompatible with lyx-2.40. 2.40 breaks 2.36  documents.  It also doesn't accept our standard bibliography format. I'm close to a submission, so I don't want to deal with how much better 2.4 is.  I have been able to compile 2.36 from sources, but now it seems that I need python2.7 to run it. Again, I'm not interested in upgrading their python code. It would be ideal simply to install lyx 2.36 and all of its dependences from 22.04

Try installing this this deb package https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/amd64/lyx/download. There is no way it should depend on python2.7. 22.04 uses python3 by default. python2.7 reached end of life in 2020

If that does not work, use Lubuntu 22.04 in a VM

OK, so my problem was that I wasn't running the newly compiled binary from the top lyx directory. Also, I had to move the .lyx directory so that 2.36 cold build its own. It apparently comes with all of the publishers and correct templates. Thanks very much for your suggestions, and for the clarification about python.

Please write your own answer in the textbox below. It will help future users

The solution was to compile from sources for the 2.36 version of lyx that is part of the 22.04 distribution. This involved care with qt5 dependencies, and on compiling with an older version of g++ (11 worked for me.) Finally, to test the compilation, run the newly compiled binary, residing in the src/ subdirectory, from the top directory of the lyx-2.3.6 source tree, and remove the .lyx directory created by lyx 2.4 that resides in your top home directory. You can just make install for it to be placed in /usr/local/bin. That way, you can repurpose the icon on a panel, if, like me, you use gnome-flashback.
